# Search Google Drive files directly from the Chrome search bar?

Tags: google-drive, search, google-chrome

Is there a way (perhaps a Chrome extension) to show Google Drive search results in my Chrome autocomplete menu?

For example in this image, if I had a Google Docs or Google Sheets called "orange juice" it would show up in this list alongside those history items and search suggestions.

[image: Chrome search bar]

Comment: Here's a way to do it by adding a search option in Chrome. No extension needed. https://plus.google.com/110453954461222492703/posts/TzRvGwEEFrW

Comment: Thanks @AlE. but I'd rather not have to remember to type a prefix

Comment: Sure, I grok that. All of the other solutions I've seen do it that way, though. Even the extensions that purport to give you this functionality are really just adding the custom search option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but Google has a Gmail search "field trial" that incorporates searching your Google Drive and Google Sites in any search you use in Gmail. It's only available in the U.S. in English for @gmail.com addresses.

More information at [Search Field Trial](https://www.google.com/experimental/gmailfieldtrial).